# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '107.24'

Tags: python

i am new in python, i just try to play a video in avg player through python. All the videos are played successfully, but one video has through this value error. i am not sure why this error was happened . if you know describe me.

Comment: Apparently, 107.24 is not an integer number.

Answer (score 3):

The specific problem arises because the software tries to interpret `107.24` as an integer number, which it is not.

Why it does this, or where this number is coming from, is really hard to tell from the little information given in your question.

Comment: I guess the problem should be closed as the OP didn't gave appropriate info.

Answer (score 1):

`'107.24'` is a float string and int() can't convert a `float` string, use `float()`.

```
>>> a='107.24'
>>> int(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '107.24'

>>> float(a)
107.24
```

Comment: Or use `round` such as `int(round(107.24))` for the string literal it gets uglier `int(round(float('107.24')))`

Comment: @NiekdeKlein `int(round(float('...')))` is different than just `int(float('...'))` -- which one you want is another question entirely.

Comment: @mgilson I stand corrected, int(float()) always rounds down, while int(round(float())) rounds to clostest int.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein -- correct.  Of course, in the context of the OP's question, it is a little ambiguous what behavior is desired...I think the real problem is they're trying to cast a float string to an int in the first place.  My hunch is that the problem is where the string is coming from ... but we can't really tell that with the information given.